# Why does sql hang up when opening multiple cursors in python?

Tags: python, mysql, cursor, migration

Im trying to take date from one database and insert into another. My function hangs up after attempting to update and results in an error 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'.  Is this because of multiple cursors being open and how might I work around it.

```
soc = MySQLdb.connect(foobarparams)

db = MySQLdb.connect(foobarparams)

def getallinfo(self):
    cursor = soc.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM firm_contributor')
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor2 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)


    for i in result:
        user = i['author_id']

        query = 'SELECT * FROM ed_users WHERE id =' + str(user)
        cursor2.execute(query)
        result = cursor2.fetchall()

        display_name = result[0]['display_name']
        email_address = result[0]['user_email']
        registered_date = result[0]['user_registered']

        update = "UPDATE firm_contributor SET display_name='%s', email_address='%s', registered_date='%s' WHERE author_id=%s" % (display_name, email_address, registered_date, user)
        print update
        cursor.execute(update)
        cursor.commit()

    cursor.close()
    cursor2.close()
```

Comment: where does the `soc` in `soc.cursor()` comes from?

Comment: there are 2 different databases that i have to connect to. i just edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code related to `cursor`, I notice that you are doing something very similar to:

```
cursor = soc.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM firm_contributor')
result = cursor.fetchall()

update = "UPDATE firm_contributor SET display_name='...'"
cursor.execute(update)
cursor.commit()
```

It seems possible that the `select` statement is getting a read lock on the `firm_contributor` table, and then the update is attempting to get a write-lock on the table, and hitting problems because it already has a read-lock, so the write-lock times out.

What happens if you add either:

```
cursor.commit()
```

or

```
cursor.close()
cursor = soc.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

after the call to `fetchall()`?

This may result in the read-lock being released, and the write-lock working.

Comment: the solution was very bizarre. i stringified the update query string after string format and it worked; update = str(update).  i do not know how that caused a write-lock error. but thanks a lot for responding